# Cannot read SHP polygon using Geopandas

Tags: python, shapefile, geopandas, fiona, pandas

I am trying to read ESRI SHP Polygon using geopandas:

```
polygon=gpd.read_file(r'Path.shp', encoding='utf-8', driver='ESRI Shapefile')
```

But I am getting this error:

> NotImplementedError: A polygon does not itself provide the array
> interface. Its rings do.

I wasn't sucessful even with GDB or ZIP file import, - although I am able to read points.

Comment: This is perfectly correct syntax so something must be wrong with the shapefile or with your python or geopandas installation. Does it fail to read any shapefile, or just this one? Does this shapefile read okay into anything else? Can you share the shapefile (with the .shx and .dbf files)?

Comment: I was able to read point Layer without any issue. I've exported this polygon shp file with all additional files from ArcGIS Pro.

Comment: I do not understand this part of your function call: `r'Path.shp'`. What does the `r` stand for? Is it missing an equal sign? Should it be there at all?

Comment: I am using Jupyter Notebook. - you can ad this r' before path and dont need to swap the slashes.

Comment: @ChloeG `r'Some Text` is a python [raw string](https://www.askpython.com/python/string/python-raw-strings)

Comment: What does `ogrinfo -al` (warning: long output) say about it-- can you load it into qgis?

Comment: @Barry Carter here is the log: [link](https://codeshare.io/MN33b3)